# If repository shouldn't return DTO, how can I return entities with number of children entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-access-layer, dto

I have read repository shouldn't return DTO but entity. So how can I return list of entities with number of children entities?

That is mine entity in database:

```
public class Note
{
    [Key] 
    public int NoteId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have in repository:

```
public IEnumerable<Note> GetNotes()
{
    return context.Notes.OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToList();
}
```

and in service:

```
public class NoteWithCommentsCountDTO
{
    public Note Note { get; set; }
    public int NoteCommentsCount { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<NoteWithCommentsCountDTO> GetNotesWithNoSpamCommentsCount()
{
    IEnumerable<NoteWithCommentsCountDTO> notesDTO = _notesRepository.GetNotes()
        .Select(x =>
        new NoteWithCommentsCountDTO
        {
            Note = x,
            NoteCommentsCount = x.Comments.Where(y => y.IsSpam == false).Count()
        });

    return notesDTO;
}
```

Unfortunatelly Entity Framework generates as many SQL queries as number of notes.

I can eliminate that problem if I use DTO in repository:

```
public IEnumerable<NoteWithCommentsCountDTO> GetNotesWithNoSpamCommentsCount()
{
    IQueryable<NoteWithCommentsCountDTO> notesDTO = context.Notes
        .Include(x => x.Comments)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Title)
        .Select(x =>
        new NoteWithCommentsCountDTO
        {
            Note = x,
            NoteCommentsCount = x.Comments.Where(y => y.IsSpam == false).Count() 
        }).ToList();

    return notesDTO;
}
```

Now Entity Framework generates one SQL query but I return DTO from repository, not entity - what is the solution?

Comment: Go with returning DTO from repository.  That's totally acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Include` in the data layer to prefetch the `Comments` for each `Note`.

```
public IEnumerable<Note> GetNotes()
{
    return context.Notes.OrderBy(x => x.Title).Include(x => x.Comments).ToList();
}
```

Function reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: But I need only number of comments, not all comments

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with entities. Entities should be the exact equivalent of tables.

You have 2 solutions 
1. You either use DTOs, as in your example
or

2. you use dynamic types (it's the same as DTOs but you don't actually have to create the classes).
Something like:

```
public dynamic GetNotesWithNoSpamCommentsCount()
{
    var notesDTO = _notesRepository.GetNotes()
        .Select(x =>
        new 
        {
            Note = x,
            NoteCommentsCount = x.Comments.Where(y => y.IsSpam == false).Count()
        });

    return notesDTO;
}
```

In my opinion, option no.1 is the best solution, specially if you're developing an n-tier application (more details on how to map entities to business logic check [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319584/how-to-map-entity-framework-model-classes-with-business-layer-class-in-n-tier-ar)).